# Uniform homeomorphism of Frechet nuclear spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Given a Frechet space X which is uniformly homeomorphic with a nuclear (Frechet) space, does it follow that X is also nuclear?

Comment: You have probably seen somewhere that all separable Frechet spaces are homeomorphic. For *uniform* homeomorphism this isn't true. The first result stated in lecture notes of Pisier (ask Google for *uniformly homeomorphic Banach spaces*) states that a locally convex space which is uniformly homeomorphic to a Banach space is itself a Banach space (more precisely, isomorphic in the category of locally convex spaces to a Banach space).

Comment: Thanks so much, Jochen for drawing my attention to the stated result. This result actually appears in Benjamini-Lindenstrauss "Geometric Functional Analysis" that I had seen years ago, but in a different context and so couldnt relate to it as a possible answer to my question. In particular, a nuclear Frechet sp can never be uniformly homeomorphic to a Banach space, unless both are finite dimensional, having the same dimension. However, the question for uniform homeomorphism between non-normable Frechet spaces remains!

Comment: Actually, the stated result does not really provide a counterexample to my question. After all, the existence of a uniform homeomorphism between a nuclear Frechet space and a Banach space forces the latter space to be finite dimensional, and hence nuclear! Whether it happens in general, i.e. for non-normable Frechet spaces is the question.

Comment: I did not claim to answer your question.